# Can you make a feature that allows users to choose color C# (Console)

Tags: c#, colors, console

Any ideas? I have a way but that would only change from downwards, and the menu is in the top.

Comment: not a clear question, no code sample of what you've done so far, no example of previous research, kindda looks like homework.

Comment: Yes you can.. .... now go read up

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("input BackgroundColor:");
        string bcolor = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("input ForegroundColor:");
        string fcolor = Console.ReadLine();
        ChangeColorConsole(bcolor, fcolor);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void ChangeColorConsole(string bvalue, string fvalue)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), bvalue);
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), fvalue);
    }
}
```

Comment: You must Set BackgroundColor  and ForegroundColor  together. And Clear Console